# AngularJS: How can we use ng-Message in a generic way?

Tags: angularjs

e.g.
with these variables in the scope:

```
"model":    {"$error": {"required": true, "anotherValidation": false}}
"messages": {"required": "This is required!", "anotherValidation": "Another validation has failed on this."}
```

I am able to show it with something like this:

```
<div ng-messages="model.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">{{messages.required}}</div>
    ..
</div>
```

But we are providing a framework where the set of validations like "required" or the associated message is not known in advance, so I would like to make it generic, something like:

```
<div ng-messages="model.$error">
    <div ng-repeat="(err, occurred) in model.$error">
         <div ng-message="{{err}}">{{messages.{{err}}}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This obviously doesn't work, but looking for a generic template like this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div ng-repeat="(x,y) in model.$error">
        <div ng-if="y"  ng-message={{x}}>{{messages[x]}}</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: In the UI it works, but on the console this error message appears(tried with 1.4 beta):
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at forEach.attr (.../angular.js:2943:15)
at Object.JQLite.(anonymous function) [as attr] (../angular.js:3042:9)
at Object.$get.Attributes.$set (../angular.js:6907:28)
at interpolateFnWatchAction (../angular.js:8187:28)
at interpolateFnWatcher (../angular.js:10370:26)
at Object.watchGroupAction [as fn] (../angular.js:14749:13)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (../angular.js:15077:29)

Comment: @Denero Sorry i can't help you with that. I tried in the last stable version: 1.3.14 and it works without problems